# How to fill an array with a fixed value of datetime64 data type in NumPy?

Tags: python, numpy, datetime64

I want to fill a numpy array with a fixed datetime64 value. The output should look something like this:

```
array(['2012-09-01', '2012-09-01', '2012-09-01', '2012-09-01',
       '2012-09-01'], dtype='datetime64[D]')
```

Where the shape of the array and the date value are variable.

Currently I am doing it this way:

```
shape = (5, )
date = "2012-09"

date_array = np.ones(shape=shape) * np.timedelta64(0, 'D') + np.datetime64(date)
```

I was wondering if there is a shorter and more readable way to get the same output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`numpy.full`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.full.html):

```
out = np.full(shape, np.datetime64(date))

# or
out = np.full(shape, date, dtype='datetime64[D]')
```

Or [`numpy.tile`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html):

```
out = np.tile(np.array(date, dtype='datetime64[D]'), shape)
```

Or [`numpy.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) and [`reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.reshape.html):

```
out = np.repeat(np.array(date, dtype='datetime64[D]'),
                np.product(shape)).reshape(shape)
```

*NB. for a single dimension `np.repeat(np.array(date, dtype='datetime64[D]'), 5)` is enough.*

Output:

```
array(['2012-09-01', '2012-09-01', '2012-09-01', '2012-09-01',
       '2012-09-01'], dtype='datetime64[D]')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [numpy.broadcast_to](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html#numpy-broadcast-to) (which is significantly faster if `shape` is large):

```
np.broadcast_to(np.datetime64(date, "D"), shape)
```

Output:

```
array(['2012-09-01', '2012-09-01', '2012-09-01', '2012-09-01',
       '2012-09-01'], dtype='datetime64[D]')
```

Timings:

```
shape = 500, 500

%timeit np.full(shape, np.datetime64(date))
%timeit np.full(shape, date, dtype='datetime64[D]')
%timeit np.tile(np.array(date, dtype='datetime64[D]'), shape)
%timeit np.repeat(np.array(date, dtype='datetime64[D]'), np.product(shape)).reshape(shape)
%timeit np.broadcast_to(np.datetime64(date, "D"), shape)
```

Output:

```
35 µs ± 154 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
36.4 µs ± 95.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
1.08 ms ± 294 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
807 µs ± 4.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
4.21 µs ± 6.31 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
```